# Cross Compile bcm2835-1.42 library for raspberry pi.

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to Cross compile library bcm2835-1.42 for my raspberry pi board in Ubuntu.
Download library and cross compiled using following commands:

> wget http: www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.42.tar.gz
>
> tar -xvf bcm2835-1.42.tar.gz
>
> cd bcm2835-1.42
>
> ./configure -host=arm -prefix=$(DEVELROOT) CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 ar=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar-4.8
>
> make

when i have make sources code i stuck with following error message.

> /tmp/ccxDzazg.s: Assembler messages:
>
> /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:299: Error: invalid barrier type -- `dmb ldr r0,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:365: Error: invalid barrier type --`dmb str r1,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:453: Error: invalid barrier type -- `dmb ldr r0,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:480: Error: invalid barrier type --`dmb str r1,[r6] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:644: Error: invalid barrier type -- `dmb str r1,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:731: Error: invalid barrier type --`dmb str r1,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:807: Error: invalid barrier type -- `dmb str r1,[r0] dmb'
>   /tmp/ccxDzazg.s:868: Error: invalid barrier type --`dmb str r1,[r0] dmb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve, It would work fine with bcm2835-1.44 library.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use the bcm2835-1.42 library, [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=8478) on the Raspberry Pi forum suggests using QEMU with the following steps:

- With the SD card connected to the host machine, execute `sudo fdisk -l` and find the disk that matches your SD card size
- Mount the SD card with `sudo mount /dev/XXXX /mnt`(`XXXX` being the indentifier representing your SD card)
- Execute `sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static` to install qemu
- Copy over the file for the emulating to the SD card with `sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin`
- Chroot into the Pi file system `sudo chroot /mnt`
- You should now be prompted with a new command line, check it has worked with `root:/# gcc -v`
- Navigate to the project you want to compile and run the Makefile or gcc or ARM build tool you need and it will start building
- When you're done, type this in to exit the chroot `exit`
- Then unmount the device `sudo unmount /dev/sdc2`